# Android view height/width changes reverted to height/width defined in xml on position change (scroll)

Tags: android, android-layout

In my Android XML file, I've defined the properties of a view as

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlMedia"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp">
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

In my code, I reuse this XML file in different activities but in one particular Activity, I want the layout to be of a specific height where it maintains the correct aspect ratio of the members inside. I use my method below to update the container's height.

```
private void setupMediaHeight(final ViewHolder vh) {
    if (mContext instanceof DetailsActivity) {
        vh.ivPhoto.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                Drawable d = vh.ivPhoto.getDrawable();
                float ratio = ((float) d.getIntrinsicHeight() / ((float) d.getIntrinsicWidth()));
                int aspectFitHeight = Math.round(ratio * ((float) vh.ivPhoto.getWidth()));
                vh.rlMedia.getLayoutParams().height = aspectFitHeight;
                vh.ivPhoto.getLayoutParams().height = aspectFitHeight;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So with the code above, everything looks as it should but when my view scrolls or changes, the cell is changed back to it's default height of 150dp. I would prefer not to create a second XML file just for the sake of one property and I don't know if adding an onLayout listener and resetting the height each time would be the best solution. I'm wondering if there were some way to change height "rule" of 150dp I set for views in this one particular activity.

EDIT:

This is how I inflate the layout

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Post object = getItem(position);
    ((PostView) v).setup(object, mContext);
    return v;
}
```

The method setupMediaHeight is something I call in the setup method after the photo has been fetched. The code below is where I try and setup the dimensions:

```
if (photoFile != null) {
    //Get singleton instance of ImageLoader
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    //Load the image from the url into the ImageView.
    imageLoader.displayImage(photoFile.getUrl(), vh.ivPhoto, new ImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String s, View view) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String s, View view, FailReason failReason) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String s, View view, Bitmap bitmap) {
            Drawable pic = vh.ivPhoto.getDrawable();
            setupMediaHeight(vh);
        }

        @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String s, View view) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot .requestLayout() after change LayoutParams

Comment: Maybe the best approach is try to update the height after you inflate this layout. Could you post the code where you inflate this relativelayout?

Comment: @vandaics ah! requestLayout fixes it! Thanks!